# C++ errors in making a program to translate to and from Pig Latin

Tags: c++, string

I'm currently working on a school assignment in C++. The purpose of the program is to translate a string of unknown length to or from Pig Latin. The professor will be compiling and running it from a Unix command line, so he will be feeding the string to the program via the shell. As I've started programming with Java, I've had to pick C++ up for this course.

After compiling the following code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype>   // used for isalnum() and isupper()
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

// function prototyping for custom functions
string toPigLatin(string);
string fromPigLatin(string);
string turnWordToPigLatin(string);
string fromPigLatinWordTranslation(string);
bool isAvowel(char);
bool isPunctuation(char);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // this is how command line args get passed in C++
{
enum { TOPIG, FROMPIG } mode;
if (argc == 1)
{ // note one argument: the name of the program is in argv[0]
    mode = TOPIG;
}
else if (argc != 2)
{
    // this is an error case. Print some kind of message
    cout << "Warning! Program started with too many command line arguments! To run this program,
                             you must include one of the two" << endl;
    cout << "argument TOPIG or FROMPIG so it will function correctly. If no arguments are
 supplied, this program will default to" << endl;
    cout << "operating in TOPIG mode."  << endl;
    return 1;
}
else
{
    string userArg (argv[1]); // turn the C string argument into a C++ string
    if (userArg =="topig")
    {
        mode = TOPIG;
    }
    else if (userArg =="frompig")
    {
        mode = FROMPIG;
    }
    else
    {
        // print some error!
        return 1;
    }
}

string toSend = "";       // check for incoming text to translate. If no text, give warning
                          // message
                          // else build a string to pass to translation functions
if ( cin.getline() = null)
{
     cout << "Warning! No text given to translate! Exitting program!" << endl;
}
else
{
    while (cin.getline() != null)
    {
          toSend.append( cin.getline() );
    }
}

// decide where to send the built string
if (mode = TOPIG)
    {
        string received = toPigLatin(toSend);
    }
else
    {
        string received = fromPigLatin(toSend);
    }

cout << received << endl;
return 0;
}

//function list; double check prototyping above.
string toPigLatin(string notPigLatin)
{
   string notPigLatin;
   string emptyString="";
   string isPigLatin="";
   string wordToConvert ="";
   char *charpointer = notPigLatin;            // points to beginning of the string
   char letterHeldInPointer = charpointer;     // holds the first letter in the string to convert

   while(&letterHeldInPointer != '\0')         // iterate through the string to examine letters
                                               // ending at the null terminator.
   {
       if ((&letterHeldInPointer = ' ') || (&letterHeldInPointer = '-'))     //
       {
          turnWordToPigLatin(*emptystring);
          strcpy(isPigLatin, emptyString);     // copies word over to isPigLatin string
          emptyString="";                      // clears out the empty string for further
          strcpy(isPigLatin, &letterHeldInPointer);
          *charpointer++;                      // move pointer forward one position
                                               // after copying spaces in
       }
       else
       {
           strcpy(emptyString, &letterHeldInPointer);
       }
       *charpointer++;                         // move pointer forward one position
   }
}

string turnWordToPigLatin(stringToCheck)
{
string stringToCheck;
int i = 0
string beganWithAVowel = "way";
string didNotStartWithVowel = "ay";
string tempString;

if ( stringToCheck[i]==isAvowel(stringToCheck, i) )
   { 
   strcat(stringToCheck, beganWithAVowel);
   }

else
    {
    while ( stringToCheck[i] != isAvowel(stringToCheck, i) )
          {
            strcat( tempString, stringToCheck[i]);
            i++;
          }
    strcat( tempString, didNotStartWithVowel);       // builds the end of the word, ie the
                                                     //    constanants plus
                                                     // the string literal "ay"
    stringToCheck.erase(0, i);                       // this removes the above from the original
                                                     // string to the first vowel
    strcat(stringToCheck, tempString)                // this is where the modifed tempstring gets
                                                     // moved to the end of the
                                                     // original string
    tempString.erase(0, tempString.length() );       // clears out tempstring to avoid hiccups if
                                                     // this is iterated through
                                                     // again in the future. Also, frees up
                                                     // memory.
    }

return stringToCheck;
}

bool isAvowel(&stringToCheck)
{     switch(stringToCheck[i])
      case 'a':
      case 'e':
      case 'i':
      case 'o':
      case 'u':
      case 'A':
      case 'E':
      case 'I':
      case 'O':
      case 'U':
           return true;
           break;
      default:
           return false;
           break;
}
bool isPunctuation(&stringToCheck)
{     switch(stringToCheck)
      case '.':
      case '?':
      case '!':
           return true;
           break;
      default:
           return false;
           break;
}
string fromPigLatin(string isPigLatin)
{
   string isPigLatin;
   string wordConvertedFromPigLatin;
   string word;                   // this is to be used to translate words from Pig Latin to
                                  // normal English.
   string modifiedstring;         // this is the final translation of the input which will be
                                    // returned to main
   char *i = &isPigLatin;         // used to cycle through the isPigLatin string, initialized to
                                    // the beginning of it

   while (i != '\0')       // start at the beginning and works until the end of the entire string
   {
         if(&i == ' ')         // if the character in i is a space, add it to the modified string
         {
               strcpy(modifiedstring, isPigLatin[i]);
               i++;
         }
         else if(isPunctuation(&isPigLatin[i]))
         {
               strcpy(modifiedstring, isPigLatin[i]);
               i++;
         }

         while(&i != ' ') && (&i != isPunctuation(&isPigLatin[i]))
         {
                  strcpy(word, isPigLatin[i]);        // builds a word out of the string which
                                                      // gets translated below
                  i++;
         }

         strcpy(modifiedstring, fromPigLatinWordTranslation(word));
   }

   return modifiedString;
}

string fromPigLatinWordTranslation(word)
{
   string fenster;                  // It's a Usual Suspects joke/reference. The word being 
                                    // translated gets put here.
   string inEnglishPlease;          // Don't worry if you've never seen it. inEnglishPlease is
                                    // where the piglatin word
                                    // ends up after trasnlation
   int i;
   char tempholder;                // used to hold the last character in Fenster

   if ( fenster[(fenster.length()-3)] =='w')        // This if else statement is used to figure
                                                    // out of the word being
   {                                             // converted began with a vowel or not.
       i = 3;
   }
   else
   {
       i = 2;
   }

   for (i; i <0; i--)                               // and here is where the above if/else
                                                    // statement comes into play
   {
       fenster.pop_back();                              // The .pop_back() function peels back the
                                                    // last letter in a string
   }

   tempholder = &fenster[(fenster.length()-1)];

   if ( isupper(fenster[0]) )                       // If the word being translated originally
                                                    // began with an uppercase
   {                                                // letter, this segment makes it lowercase, 
                                                    // and capitializes the proper
        toupper(tempholder);                        // first character of the word.
        tolower(fenster[0]);
   }
   fenster.pop_back();
   strcpy(inEnglishPlease, tempholder);
   strcpy(inEnglishPlease, fenster);
   return inEnglishPlease;
}
```

Since I started my academic track learning Java, I've become used to being able to access JavaDocs for reference or to clear up any errors. I've found no such repository of easy reference for C++. So, when I compiled, I got the following errors. Can anyone help me decode and un-fubar the following errors:

```
   *piglatin.cpp:9:55: error: ctype: No such file or directory piglatin.cpp: In function 'int
main(int, char**)':

piglatin.cpp:56: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char,
std::char_traits<char> >::getline()' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-
linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/istream:593: note: candidates are:
std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::getline(_CharT*,
std::streamsize, _CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/istream:405: note:
std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::getline(_CharT*,
std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

piglatin.cpp:56: error: 'null' was not declared in this scope

piglatin.cpp:62: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char,
std::char_traits<char> >::getline()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/istream:593: note: candidates
are: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::getline(_CharT*,
std::streamsize, _CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/istream:405: note:
std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::getline(_CharT*,
std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

piglatin.cpp:64: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char,
std::char_traits<char> >::getline()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/istream:593: note: candidates 
are: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::getline(_CharT*,
std::streamsize, _CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/istream:405: note:
std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::getline(_CharT*,
std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

piglatin.cpp:78: error: 'received' was not declared in this scope
piglatin.cpp: In function 'std::string toPigLatin(std::string)':

piglatin.cpp:85: error: declaration of 'std::string notPigLatin' shadows a parameter

piglatin.cpp:89: error: cannot convert 'std::string' to 'char*' in initialization

piglatin.cpp:90: error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'

piglatin.cpp:94: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

piglatin.cpp:94: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

piglatin.cpp:96: error: 'emptystring' was not declared in this scope

piglatin.cpp:97: error: cannot convert 'std::string' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char*
strcpy(char*, const char*)'

piglatin.cpp:99: error: cannot convert 'std::string' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char*
strcpy(char*, const char*)'

piglatin.cpp:104: error: cannot convert 'std::string' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char*
strcpy(char*, const char*)'
piglatin.cpp: At global scope:

piglatin.cpp:110: error: 'std::string turnWordToPigLatin' redeclared as different kind of symbol

piglatin.cpp:17: error: previous declaration of 'std::string turnWordToPigLatin(std::string)'

piglatin.cpp:110: error: 'stringToCheck' was not declared in this scope*
```

Comment: Did you even try to look up some things like `getline`? There is plenty of documentation available and it is not hard to find.

Comment: That's a lot to look at.  My advice: start again, build each part of the functionality seperately, start off making sure you can read a line of input, then write a function to split it into words, then write the translation function.  Test each step as you go.  As it is, the program doesn't even default to `TOPIG` mode as described

Answer (score 0):

You are using C functions like `strcat` on `std::string`s, but they are meant to operate on C-Strings aka `char*`. Thats what most of the errors are about. You should definitely consult a beginners' book for C++ basics like the distinction between `char*` and `string` and first steps on using standard library facilities. Also try http://cppreference.com/ for a standard library reference.